# How do I remove a 1px margin from td elements?

Tags: html, css

There is a `1px` margin/padding around my `td` elements:

[image]

```
td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

How do I remove this?

Comment: post the related html and css code..

Comment: This is probably related to the `border-collapse` style and not margins. But since you only posted a picture with no markup or CSS, all anyone can do is speculate.

Comment: `table { border-collapse: collapse }` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have something that looks like this:

```css
td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Add this CSS to your page:**

```
table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Like so:

```css
table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
   <table border="1" style="border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
       <td>test</td>
       <td>test</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
       <td>test</td>
       <td>test</td>
    <tr>
  </table>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks